# R: doing multiple things within a while loop

Tags: r, fibonacci

I want to write a while loop which does two things but my code is currently only doing the first line of code written within the loop, how can I write the code so that it does both lines?

```
`x <- 30   
fibvals <- numeric(x)
evenfib <- c()
fibvals[1] <- 1
fibvals[2] <- 1
count = 1
while (count < x) { 
    count = count + 1
    fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]
} 
fibvals
count`
```

Comment: Apparently you have not set the variable `i` nor you update it inside the loop. So `fibvals[i]` is always the same

Answer (score 1):

Your loop variable is count, you're trying to use i which doesn't appear to be declared.